# How to Override Mage_Checkout_Block_Links

Tags: php, xml, magento

What is the proper way to override a method, for example, the Mage_Checkout_Block_Links::addCartLink() method.

My goal is to add some HTML before the Mage_Checkout_Block_Links::addCartLink() method. However, I don't know where to begin or which file to copy and edit under my custom theme.

I am thinking about something like this:

```
public function addLink($beforeText='<i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>')
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with simple override or with module/block rewrite( recommended but needs more efforts and Magento knowledge).

With override :
Create a Mage folder in local folder.
Copy file class Mage_Checkout_Block_Links and place it here in exact path as was in core folder.
modify function public function addCartLink().

with rewrite:
instead of mage folder you create your name space folder.
Also make sure you have a rewrite node as commented in above post

Other way:
Also if you just modify "My Cart" language defines that will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by this way:First you have to rewrite code for the core block function in your config.xml.The code will be like

```
<checkout>
        <rewrite>
            <links>My_Module_Block_Checkout_Links</links>
        </rewrite>
    </checkout>.
```

Than in your block create folder with checkout and than file wit link.php.And in link.php extend your class from `extends My_Module_Block_Checkout_Links`.Write your links function with new code.I hope this will help you.I didn't check this code , but done such work before.

Comment: THanks! I will look into it! If it works, you'll get a nice checkmark!